# How to include a missing value left out by a query containing GROUP BY?

Tags: sqlite, group-by, aggregate-functions

I'm attempting to retrieve the columns shown in the query below from a table, that contains information on houses, for *all of the houses in the table*:

```
select id, address, rooms,
  area, count ( id ), avg( area )
from house
group by rooms
order by rooms asc, area asc
;
```

The query should show the number of houses containing the same number of rooms and the average of their areas for every house in the table.

However, there are currently 2 houses that have the same number of rooms, which results in this query leaving the other house out of the result. How can I address this duplicate problem, as in how do I display information on all of the houses in the table based on the number of rooms, even if a house with the same number of rooms has already been found before?

It doesn't matter if the two rows have the same `count ( id )` and `avg ( area )`. In fact, that would be the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a CTE to get the number of houses and the average area and join to the table:

```
with cte as (
  select rooms, count(id) counter, avg(area) averagearea
  from house
  group by rooms
)
select 
  h.id, h.address, h.rooms, h.area,
  c.counter, c.averagearea
from house h inner join cte c
on c.rooms = h.rooms
order by h.rooms asc, h.area asc
```